# Compute Levenshtein Distance between two String Columns from two different dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, similarity, levenshtein-distance

I have two dataframes which contain the same string column (hostname) and I want to compute the Levenshtein distance between all possible combinations of hostnames pairs between both dataframes and put the results in a third dataframe where I keep the distance for each possible combination but also both indexes of this combination.

For example, let's say I have these two dataframes:

```
Index      Hostname
85608             dlt-rly-tracker-3.datto.com
9378      lnv7bc4241e2.1528.ozvision.ozsn.net
22791             dlt-rly-tracker-1.datto.com
88922                                 pw-file
94560     lnv7bc4241e2.1528.ozvision.ozsn.net
13245                                       -
63604                                 pw-file
435839                                pw-file
95473                                       -
13856                                 pw-file
210705                                pw-file
30046                                       -
106917            dlt-rly-tracker-2.datto.com
415925                                pw-file
170471                                pw-file
73971                                       -
86885             dlt-rly-tracker-3.datto.com
162764                                pw-file
74791                                 pw-file
```

and the second dataframe:

```
Index     Hostname
93358                  device.dattobackup.com
34067             dlt-rly-tracker-5.datto.com
18083               46.104.89.54.in-addr.arpa
96798                                 pw-file
130940                                pw-file
31476     lnv7bc4241e2.1528.ozvision.ozsn.net
149723                                pw-file
52901                                       -
308834    lnv7bc4241e2.1528.ozvision.ozsn.net
24196                                 pw-file
69038                                       -
244454    lnv7bc4241e2.1528.ozvision.ozsn.net
2867                                        -
45549                        daisy.ubuntu.com
334378                                pw-file
86006               46.104.89.54.in-addr.arpa
430257                                pw-file
86150               46.104.89.54.in-addr.arpa
65189                                 pw-file
```

What I want to do is to take the first value of hostname (dlt-rly-tracker-3.datto.com) and compute the levenshtein distance with the all values of hostnames from the second dataframe (one by one). Store the results at the end of this process in a new dataframe that will look similar to the following:

```
Indexes         Distance    Hostnames
85608-93358     23          dlt-rly-tracker-3.datto.com,device.dattobackup.com
85608-34067     60          dlt-rly-tracker-3.datto.com,dlt-rly-tracker-5.datto.com
```

I really appreciate any help to solve my problem. Thanks.

Comment: Unsure if this helps you but https://github.com/seatgeek/fuzzywuzzy is a package that uses levenshtein distance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution below will loop through both data frames and create a new dictionary with the data you want. You should then convert this dictionary to a data frame.  Let me know if this helps!

```
 dist = {}
 for rowname, row in df.iterrows(): 
      for rowname1, row1 in df1.iterrows(): 
            L = Levenstein(row.Hostname, row1.Hostname)
            dist.update( {rowname+’-‘+rowname1 : (L, row.Hostname+’,’+row1.Hostname} )
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try it and let you know.

Comment: Thanks a lot StevenSolar, your solution is what I have been looking for.

Comment: No problem! If you mark my answer as correct it'll help others with the same problem. Best of luck with your project!

Comment: @StevenSolar your answer looks exactly like what I need. However there are 2 errors I get. 

In the last row there are to open brackets and only one closing bracket. Where is the second closing bracket meant to go? 

Secondly, which package do you install to use the Levenstein function?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my proposition to solve it.

```
import pandas as pd
from nltk import edit_distance
```

Here you need to create your two DataFrames. I assume that they are called:

df1

df2

```
outputList = []
for rowLeft  in df1.iterrows():
    for rowRight in df2.iterrows():
        indexes = str(rowRight[1][0]) + "-" + str(rowLeft[1][0])
        distance = edit_distance(rowRight[1][1],rowLeft[1][1])
        hostNames = rowRight[1][1] + "-" + rowLeft[1][1]
        outputList.append({"Indexes": indexes, "Distance":distance, "Hostnames":hostNames})

outputDf = pd.DataFrame(outputList)
```